# Strange HttpResponse in Android

Tags: android, http, httpresponse

I am having an unusual problem regarding the following code in an android application.

```
public InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (10 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    try
    {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

      final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK){

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
           return getResponseEntity.getContent();
      }
      else
      {
          Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                  "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
              return null;
      }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
      Log.e("Methods", "HTTP Error", e);
      return null;

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      Log.e("Methods", "Connection Error", e);
      return null;

    }   
 }
```

Within the application I attempt to connect to a localhost.(In an AsyncTask)

```
InputStream source = retrieveStream("http://10.0.2.2:27080/testdb/_hello")
```

When running on the emulator, this code works fine and if the localhost is down, "source" is returned as null as expected. Similarly when running the code on a mobile device (HTC Nexus One, Android Version 2.2), the code reports "source" as null as expected.
However when running the same APK on another mobile device (Samsung Galaxy S2, Android Version 4.0.3, samsung release), the status code returned is given as HttpStatus.SC_OK, even though it couldnt possibly be connecting to the localhost. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: How do you install/run it on Galaxy S2, same as Emulator/HTC Nexus One (via adb debug), or directly install and run apk without adb connection?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, I have tried both approaches with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Android > 3.0 does not allow to execute web request on `Main UI Thread`. you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make web request. IN android > 3.0

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, however I should have mentioned that the method is actually called in the doInBackround method of an AsyncTask. I have update the question to state this.